# Tikz image with remember picture combined with custom page numbering

Tags: tikz-pgf, page-numbering, tikzmark

I have a problem combining TIKZ-pictures when using custom pagenumbers.

I modify my page numbers as shown in the upmost answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2753477/how-do-i-make-custom-page-numbering-in-latex).

When drawing a simple TIKZ-image, I recieve the error `! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).`

I have tried a lot of variants and found that the problem is the combination of a tikzmark and the tikz option `remember picture`.

The problem is shown below in the MWE. If the `remember picture` option is removed, all works fine, except the position of the tikz-image is offset which is not feasible for me.

What I have already tried:

- Modifying the `\thepage` command using `{}` brackets, other signs etc. What I've found is that adding a `.` rather than a `-` between the section and page number solves the problem, since tikz seemingly interprets this as a valid floating point number.
- Resetting the pagestyle before the picture starts -> no effect at all

I'm using pdflatex on a Windows-machine.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[english,footsepline,listof=totoc]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
    \renewcommand{\thepage}{\arabic{section}-\arabic{page}}
\begin{document}
\tikzmark{mark1}

Text

\tikz[overlay,remember picture]\draw[red,] ({pic cs:mark1} |- 2,2) -- (3,3 |- 4,4);
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

A fix was posted for the issue responsible for the problem in response to [How to make tikzpicture (with "remember picture" and "tikzmark") work with SIG ACM template?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/342885/). (The question there is different, so yours is not a duplicate, but the root cause is the same.)

I believe the fix will probably end up in the next version of `tikzmark`. Basically, you just need to alter `tikzmark` to use `\arabic{page}` rather than `\thepage`, which makes it a lot more robust.

The following code should fix `\pgfmark` as well as the case involving `tikzpicture`. This isn't mentioned in the other Q&A, but I think it will be needed in more complex cases involving Ti*k*Z, too, such as use of `\subnode`.

```
\documentclass[english,footsepline,listof=totoc]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{
  every picture/.append style={%
    execute at end picture={%
      \ifpgfrememberpicturepositiononpage%
      \edef\pgf@temp{%
        \noexpand\write\noexpand\pgfutil@auxout{%
          \string\savepicturepage{\pgfpictureid}{\noexpand\arabic{page}}}}%
      \pgf@temp
      \fi%
    },
  },
}
\renewcommand\pgfmark[1]{%
    \bgroup
    \global\advance\pgf@picture@serial@count by1\relax%
    \edef\pgfpictureid{pgfid\the\pgf@picture@serial@count}%
      \pgfsys@markposition{\pgfpictureid}%
    \edef\pgf@temp{%
      \noexpand\write\noexpand\pgfutil@auxout{%
        \string\savepicturepage{\pgfpictureid}{\noexpand\arabic{page}}}}%
    \pgf@temp
    \protected@write\pgfutil@auxout{}{%
      \string\savepointas{\tikzmark@pp@name{#1}}{\pgfpictureid}{0pt}{0pt}}%
    \egroup
  }
\makeatother
\renewcommand{\thepage}{\arabic{section}-\arabic{page}}
\begin{document}
\tikzmark{mark1}

Text

\tikz[overlay,remember picture]\draw[red,] ({pic cs:mark1} |- 2,2) -- (3,3 |- 4,4);
\end{document}
```