# How to make tikzpicture (with "remember picture" and "tikzmark") work with SIG ACM template?

Tags: tikz-pgf, acm, tikzmark

I want to use `\tikzmark` outside `tikzpicture` to remember some coordinates, and then use them inside `tikzpicture` (it seems a rather standard thing). I have this minimal working example that draws a rectangle:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\begin{document}

Some random text outside\tikzmark{label}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
\draw (0.1,0.1) rectangle (pic cs:label);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The link to the class is here:

https://www.acm.org/binaries/content/assets/publications/article-templates/sig-alternate-05-2015.cls

Now, the problem happens when I switch to a SIG ACM format, for example this one:

```
\documentclass{sig-alternate-05-2015}
```

Then, this error happens (but during the SECOND Latex pass):

```
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \thepage 
l.13 \draw (0.1,0.1) rectangle (pic cs:label)
                                             ;
?
```

Now, I tracked the problem down to the `remember picture` part - if it's removed, the error disappears. However, it seems crucial to use with the tikzmark feature.

I will be grateful for any hints.

Comment: for journals it's better to externalize your pictures as you can't be sure whether they will compile enough number of times to get the final result.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I would do it if it was just a picture. However, the example above is minimal to make it simple - my ultimate goal is to put these tikz pictures onto a listing, and this cannot be externalized (or at least not easily).

Comment: Does the class not have page numbers (even invisible ones)? Is this intended for an online format or something?

Comment: What happens if you add `\pagenumbering{arabic}` after `\begin{document}`? [Note: you may get an error. I don't know the class: this is by way of finding stuff out rather than proposing a solution.]

Comment: Can you provide a link to the class as it is not in TeX Live?

Comment: Yes, I added the link to the question.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that `\thepage` is set to `\relax` in the `\write` statement and hence is written literally to the `aux` file, instead of being replaced by the page number. I suggest to patch the `tikzmark` library such that it doesn't use `\thepage`. Add the following lines after `\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}`.

```
\usepackage{xpatch}
\expandafter\xpatchcmd
   \csname pgfk@/tikz/every picture/.@cmd\endcsname
   {\thepage}{\arabic{page}}{}{}
```

Comment: I have a vague memory of this being raised before, but the source for `tikzmark` still has `\thepage` so I guess if it did then I didn't get round to fixing it.  `\arabic{page}` is far more robust than `\thepage` so I'll put that in the next release.

Comment: Thank you! This worked like a charm. I also provided the link to the CLS file in the question.